# How to apply Java Swing in a different class?

Tags: java, swing, class, oop

I have 2 different classes,

Main window:

```
package opdracht4;

public class Opdracht4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App();
    }
}
```

And this class

```
package opdracht4;

import javax.swing.*;

public class App() {
    JFrame app = new JFrame();
    JPanel paneel = new JPanel();
    
    paneel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
}
```

I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong here, as I'm not the best in Java, so could anyone tell me whats wrong at line 5 in the second class?

Comment: In order to tell you whats wrong you need to explain what you expect to happen first. Please [edit] your post and add what you want to happen.

Comment: This line of your code is **not** valid java syntax: `public class App() {` Did you make a mistake when copying your code to the question?

Comment: *I'm not the best in Java,* - then start from working examples and make customizations. For example to learn how to use borders check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for examples to download. There are also examples on other Swing basics.

Answer (score 2):

The line `paneel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));` is out of any method, you need to add a constructor to the class `App`, for example:

```
public App(){
    paneel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
    app.setVisible(true);// to display the JFrame
}
```

Comment: Well spotted! OP: Note that is line 9, not line 5. Always copy/paste compiler, error and exception output! **Edit:** OK I think I just spotted the likely cause of error in line 5. The class name should not end in `()`.